# I have difficulty finding "ANGOSTURA" bitters, is there any substitute?

Tags: substitutions, drinks, alcohol, cocktails

My preferred pre-dinner drink is the [Manathan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manhattan_%28cocktail%29), but I have difficulties finding [ANGOSTURA bitters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angostura_bitters).

Is there anything else that I could use instead of it?

Comment: Where are you looking for it and where do you live? In Atlanta, every liquor store and every grocery store would most likely stock Angostura bitters.

Comment: I'm in Québec, Canada. Here most alcohol (except beer and some wine) is are sold in the SAQ (a government-owned corporation responsible for the trade of alcoholic beverages). Meanwhile, I found it in a grocery in the past, but we moved and I cannot find it anymore.

Comment: Go to your local Pub and ask the manager if you can buy a bottle or two.  At the very least he'll tell you where he gets it from.  Typical in BC is the grocery store like you already know about.  Usually next to the Lime Cordial and other mixes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try Peychaud's Bitters (difficult to find), Fernet-Branca, orange bitters or other types of bitters.  Worcestershire sauce may also be used as a substitute but works well in savory dishes. I wouldn't recommend it for a Manhattan.

Or, if you're very ambitious you can try to make your own bitters, although the ingredient list is somewhat intimidating! Good luck!

http://spiritsandcocktails.wordpress.com/2008/04/22/how-to-make-bitters/

Comment: While another kind of bitters will round out the flavor of the cocktail nicely, it will have a completely different flavor than the inimitable Angostura.  Fee Brothers' Old-Fashioned Aromatic Bitters are the most similar in taste.

Comment: I agree with @David.

Answer (score 5):

You can also [order bitters from Amazon](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_1?url=search-alias=aps&field-keywords=fee%20brothers%20bitters&x=0&y=0). I don't know for sure if they can ship them to Canada; try it and let us know. Fee Brothers is a very old company that makes some terrific varieties. I particularly like their grapefruit bitters.

Answer (score 3):

[KegWorks](http://www.kegworks.com/) sells [Angostura bitters](http://angosturabitters.com/) and will ship to Canada - [CAD$10 for a 4-oz. bottle](http://www.kegworks.com/angostura-aromatic-cocktail-bitters-4-oz-bottle-936-p19544), or [CAD$23 for a 16-oz. bottle](http://www.kegworks.com/angostura-aromatic-cocktail-bitters-16-oz-bottle-936-p174544), plus shipping.  I've used them (for shipments to the US) and had nothing but good experiences.

Comment: Also these guys. http://thecraftybartender.com/shop/angostura-orange-bitters/

Answer (score 1):

In Quebec, it easily available in most grocery stores (Métro, IGO, Provigo) in the aisles where they have syrups (grenadines...)

Answer (score 0):

A good substitute for Angostura Bitters is to dissolve a couple of
Ricola Herb Cough Drops in a Canadian Rye Whiskey - such as Hunter Rye -
and let set for a day to dissolve.

Comment: no. that's just gross

Comment: ... but perhaps that's the attraction...

Answer (score 0):

@vecta has provided the canonical answer to which I agree.

Others provided alternate replies to the effect of *have you tried this source*, an example being Amazon.

Amazon Canada: [ANGOSTURA Aromatic Bitters, 100 Milliliters](https://www.amazon.ca/dp/B00576SHBQ/).

Answer (score -3):

a Manhattan is whiskey and sweet vermouth.  I've never put bitters in a Manhattan is my 25 years of bar tending.  I do use them in Whisky old fashioneds, though.

Comment: I think this can be seen as an answer, as it points out that there is a version of Manhattan without the bitters, and thus the OP can try just making a cocktail without a substitution. So I won't delete it despite the flags. It could be better worded, though.

Comment: @rumtscho This answer is not answering the question of “is there a substitute for ango” or a similar “what can I use in place of ango”. It's also factually incorrect and relies on personal experience over higher quality sources, such as the rich literature on the subject…or even Wikipedia.

Comment: @coreyward "factually incorrect" doesn't matter when a moderator has to decide whether to delete an answer. As for whether the "don't substitute" part should be considered an answer, this is certainly a relevant discussion. I tend to err on the side of "consider it an answer" because we frequently enough get questions where "leave it out" is indeed the best answer one can give.